# How to get javascript result in angular js model

Tags: html, angularjs

Iam binding result date to input text based on that input id , but in angular script the input value not saving in input ng model

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="10"
       ng-model="EmployeeSave.HijriDate" onclick="showCal2();"
       id="date-2" />
```

this is our input field in javascript function I am getting value from

```
function setDateFields() {
        date1.value = cal1.getDate().getDateString();
        date2.value = cal2.getDate().getDateString();
    }

function showCal1() {
    if (cal1.isHidden()) cal1.show();
    else cal1.hide();
}

function showCal2() {
    if (cal2.isHidden()) cal2.show();
    else cal2.hide();
}
```

in setdatafields function I am getting value date2.value,How to I bind this value to ng-model
of  EmployeeSave.HijriDate[ng-model]

Comment: where are you setting the value of `EmployeeSave.HijriDate`

Answer (score 1):

You must use $scope. Like this

```
 $scope.date1.value = cal1.getDate().getDateString();
```

Then in the input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="10"  ng-model="date1.value" onclick="showCal2();" id="date-2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It would defintly be better if you use Angular ng-click instead of on-click. 
HTML code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="10"
   ng-model="EmployeeSave.HijriDate" 
   ng-click="input2Clicked=!input2Clicked" />
<div ng-show="input2Clicked">THIS IS CAL2</div>
```

I don't think you are going to need the id because the controller and the view are now connected with the ng-model.
Controller Code:

```
//writing the controllers like that I better for minifiying the js files
//if you already created the module in the model file  which I really recommend
//module file must be included before the controller's file in HTML
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController',MyController);
//if you haven't created the module or the model file yet 
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('MyController',MyController);
//then the let's stare writing the controller's code
MyController.$inject=['$scope']
function MyController($scope){

}
```

can you please specify where are you getting the dates from ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set everything in scope and make sure parent objects are initialised. Like so:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        //make sure parent objects are defined
        $scope.date2 = {};
        $scope.EmployeeSave = {};

        //make sure functions are in $scope
        $scope.setDateFields = function () 
        {
            $scope.date2.value = "myDate 1/1/17";
            //assign your date variables
            $scope.EmployeeSave.HijriDate = $scope.date2.value;
        }

        $scope.setDateFields(); //don't forget to call the function

});
```

here is the code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/AKMorris/s3hn2ygw/

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope`, is interact with your views(`ng-model`) and get back to controller also.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

```js
var app = angular.module("exApp",[]);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
function setDateFields() {
        date1.value = cal1.getDate().getDateString();
        date2.value = cal2.getDate().getDateString();
        $scope.EmployeeSave.HijriDate = date2.value;
    }

/*function showCal1() {
    if (cal1.isHidden()) cal1.show();
    else cal1.hide();
}

function showCal2() {
    if (cal2.isHidden()) cal2.show();
    else cal2.hide();
}
*/
$scope.showCal2 = function() {    if (cal2.isHidden()) show();
    else hide();
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="exApp">
<div controller="ctrl">
<input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="10"
       ng-model="EmployeeSave.HijriDate" ng-click="showCal2();"/><br>
       {{EmployeeSave.HijriDate}}
       </div>
       </body>
```